# uri image source react native doesn't work

Tags: node.js, react-native

I want to retrieve image from my server with authorization i try this solution but doesn't work,
How can this be resolved?

import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://130b57da660e.ngrok.io'
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config)=>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if(token){
            config.headers.Authorization= `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
      
        return config;

    },
    
    (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
)

export default instance;
```

---

```
import ExpressApi from '../api/ExpressApi';


   const ImageApi= ({path,imageStyle})=>{

        <Image style={imageStyle}  source={ JSON.stringify(ExpressApi.get('/'+path))}/> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `source` props explanation on [React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#imagesource), you may pass `uri` and `headers` into `source` props.

Please try:

```
const ImageApi= ({path, token, imageStyle}) => (
    <Image 
        style={imageStyle}
        source={{
            uri: path,
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }}/> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is either of them.

1. The `uri` is not working (maybe due to unauthorized or the path is simply wrong, )
2. You forgot to do this `source={{ uri: "Your image path here"}}`

If I were you, I will try to log the image path and paste to browser to see if the image is accessible with the `uri`. Because if the image requires authentication, I believe the token should be attached to the `uri` if not the header, something like `xxxxxxxxx.jpg?token="your token"`